# No matching function for call to 'init_pair'

Tags: c++, ncurses

I use termux with clang. I've tried compiling the following code in clang but it outputs an error, mentioned in the title.
Here is the code.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  initscr();
  start_color();
  init_pair(1,argv[1],argv[2]);
  attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
  for (int i = 3; i < argc; ++i) {
    printw("%s",argv[i]);
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
  }
  refresh();
}
```

Comment: init_pair requires three integers as input parameters: `int init_pair(short pair, short f, short b);` so you probably want `init_pair(1,atoi(argv[1]),atoi(argv[2]));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual error message tells you what the problem is:

```
> clang -c foo.cc
foo.cc:8:1: error: no matching function for call to 'init_pair'
init_pair(1,argv[1],argv[2]);
^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/curses.h:648:28: note: candidate function not viable: no known
      conversion from 'char *' to 'short' for 2nd argument; dereference the
      argument with *
extern NCURSES_EXPORT(int) init_pair (NCURSES_PAIRS_T,NCURSES_COLOR_T,NC...
                           ^
1 error generated.
```

The `init_pair` function uses short-integer parameters (not a `char*`).  You could make it compile by converting those `char*`'s to integer, e.g.,

```
> diff -u foo.cc.orig foo.cc
--- foo.cc.orig 2020-09-21 17:35:04.000000000 -0400
+++ foo.cc      2020-09-21 17:36:42.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,11 +1,12 @@
 #include <ncurses.h>
+#include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;
 
 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 initscr();
 start_color();
-init_pair(1,argv[1],argv[2]);
+init_pair(1,atoi(argv[1]),atoi(argv[2]));
 attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
 for (int i = 3; i < argc; ++i) {
 printw("%s",argv[i]);
```

(though that's just a quick fix).